# Forgot password function fosuserbundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I have been googling for a couple hours now and cannot find any information on how to implement the "Forgot Password" functionality in FOSUserBundle

Is this part of the bundle or is it something I have to create myself.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually it is weird that you didn't find anything about it, you probably didn't search with good terms (maybe reset instead of forgot). Anyway it's a pretty simple process.
You probably read the [github documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst), it's explained there ([Step 6](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files)) that you have to import the routing.xml file and furthermore this route :

```
fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting
```

You just have to add a link in your template with the fos_user_resetting_request route :

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">Forgot password ?</a>
```

Then a click on this link will lead the user to a reset form which will ask the user email and send them an email with a security token in the link to the password edit form.

If you want to customize the render, read these docs :

- [Overriding templates](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.rst)
- [Overriding forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.rst)
- [Overriding controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.rst)

Does it help you?
Good luck!

Comment: I did search for reset password instead of forgot password. I also saw it after looking at your entry with 
php app/console router:debug i was using /resetting instead of /resetting/request thank you